# Shell Scripting. Logical ERROR

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I have written a **shell script** with a **switch case** and takes in options 1-5 and performs operations on the variables accordingly.

My code works fine though theres a small change I would like to make in my code.

When the code Enters the default case argument,after that it still prompts for "Enter two numbers: " and then prints "Invalid Option "which is inappropriate.Ideally the code should stop after invalid option.

I've just learnt shell scripting so I'm not that good at it.

**I have copy pasted my source-code below:**

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "1. Add
        2.Substract
    3.Divide
    4.Multiply
    5.Quit"

read -p "Enter an option:" option
read -p "Enter two numbes: " first second

case $option in

1)income=$[ first + second ];;
2)income=$[ first - second ];;
3)income=$[ first / second ];;
4)income=$[ first * second ];;
*)echo "Invalid Option";
    exit 1;;

esac

echo "Income=$income"

exit 0
```

**I tried using if,else ...but that doesn't serve the purpose.**
**Alternative approach:**

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

echo "1. Add
        2.Substract
    3.Divide
    4.Multiply
    5.Quit"

read -p "Enter an option:" option

if [ option > 5 ]
then 

    echo "Invalid Option"
        exit 1

else 

read -p "Enter two numbes: " first second

fi

case $option in

1)income=$[ first + second ];;
2)income=$[ first - second ];;
3)income=$[ first / second ];;
4)income=$[ first * second ];;
*)echo "Invalid Option";
    exit 1;;

esac

echo "Income=$income"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `select` builtin, it will help reduce the complexity of what you want by quite a lot. You can replace the echo/case with it.

In this case I think your problem is that you have your cases as `1.)` rather than `1)`. Your user would need to type the number *with* the period for the former to match.

Additionally, you need to have your shebang line as `#!/bin/bash`, it will not work with the space you have there.

Comment: Thank you ok I'll try select,and edit the periods :) ... +1. The shebang line works fine with the space as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a menu like this, you can use an infinity loop.

```
#! /bin/bash


while true
do
cat <<-EOF
  1. Add
  2.Substract
  3.Divide
  4.Multiply
  5.Quit
EOF
    read -p "Enter an option:" option
    read -p "Enter two numbes: " first second

    case $option in
    1) income=$((first + second ));;
    2) income=$(( first - second ));;
    3) income=$(( first / second ));;
    4) income=$(( first * second ));;
    5) exit;;
    *) echo "Invalid Option, try again";
    esac

    echo "Income=$income"
done
```

Comment: Is it that,the usage of $[..] should be avoided? or is it wrong? I'm asking this because I have used $[..] and it works fine.please explain.

Comment: no, its not wrong. just that i am used to C style that i forgot we can use square brackets as well.

Comment: This answer still doesn't solve my problem.After I hit quit it shouldn't ask for the two number again,instead just print an Error message and break out of the program..

Comment: then put `read -p "Enter two numbes: " first second` after the `case/esac`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use if else. Just take the input in the switch case.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "
      1.Add
      2.Subtract
      3.Divide
      4.Multiply
      5.Quit"

read -p "Enter an option:" option

case $option in

1)
    read -p "Enter two numbers " first second
    income=$[ first + second ];;

2)
    read -p "Enter two numbers " first second
    income=$[ first - second ];;


3)
    read -p "Enter two numbers " first second
    income=$[ first / second ];;

4)
    read -p "Enter two functions " first second
    income=$[ first * second ];;

*)echo "Invalid Option";
    exit 1;;

esac

echo "Income = $income"

exit 0
```

Or you can use function to avoid repetition of read statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

function GetInput()
{
    read -p "Enter two numbers : " first second
}



echo "
      1.Add
      2.Substract
      3.Divide
      4.Multiply
      5.Quit"

read -p "Enter an option:" option

case $option in

1)
    GetInput
    income=$[ first + second ];;

2)
    GetInput
    income=$[ first - second ];;


3)
    GetInput
    income=$[ first / second ];;

4)
    GetInput
    income=$[ first * second ];;

*)echo "Invalid Option";
    exit 1;;

esac

echo "Income = $income"

exit 0
```